# TryParse String to Int Active Patterns

Tags: f#

Hello SO I am currently trying to parse a string to an Int using active Patterns and the Int.TryParse Method. Using the old examples from 2012 it used to work something like this:

```
let (|Int|_|) str =
    match System.Int32.TryParse str with
    | true,int -> Some int
    | _ -> None
```

but now I'm getting an error telling me that the right overload of TryParse() can not be choosen. Annotating the str as a string the error persists. I hope any one of you could help me with this simple problem, thanks in advance.

Some additional Information: I am trying this using FSharp.Core 4.5.2 and .Net Core 2.1.

The Error:

> FS0041    A unique overload for method 'TryParse' could not be determined
>   based on type information prior to this program point. A type
>   annotation may be needed. Candidates: Int32.TryParse(s:
>   ReadOnlySpan<char>, result: byref<int>) : bool, Int32.TryParse(s:
>   string, result: byref<int>) : bool

Comment: Are you seeing the error in text the compiler outputs or in the Visual Studio "Error List" tab? Sometimes I see spurious results in the "Error List" tab, perhaps caused by in-editor parsing issues. Your code compiles fine in one of my open projects.

Comment: I see it inside of the "Error List" tab but the same message is also shown inside of the compiler output. It does not compile.

Answer (score 11):

Found my own mistake with the Help of [Jestar342](https://www.reddit.com/user/Jestar342) on Reddit:

```
let (|Int|_|) (str:string) =
    match System.Int32.TryParse str with
    | true,int -> Some int
    | _ -> None
```

changing str to (str:string) fixes this error.

Answer (score 5):

Consider also using a more idiomatic F# built-in [int](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-core-operators.html#int) function.

Something like...

```
let tryParseInt s = 
    try 
        s |> int |> Some
    with :? FormatException -> 
        None
```

Comment: Is there a book/guide/repository/some resource that in your opinion helps a beginner to write more idiomatic F# Code?

Comment: http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/ is an awesome resource! E.g. an [article](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/the-option-type/) about options usage. Or [pair of functions](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/exceptions/#the-pair-of-functions-approach) (X and tryX) approach for [exception handling](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/exceptions/). Or [casting of primitive types](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/cli-types/#casting-between-built-in-primitive-types), also relevant here.

Answer (score 2):

The `Span` type was recently introduced into .Net.
Before, `System.Int32.TryParse` only had one overload that expected a `string` parameter, thus, F# type inference could deduce that a string was needed. After adding `Span` there are 2 overloads and type inference cannot tell which one to use.

That is one drawback of type inference and overloaded functions: it can break existing code. Type annotation is the solution.